# How to compare current date within while loop value?

Tags: php, while-loop, advanced-custom-fields, acfpro

I have some dates for my tickets for the event like the following screenshot and I am using ACF repeater for this.

[image]

And I have a function where I am trying to compare the ticket registration start date with the current date.

```
function santy_shortcode_race_categories_event_post(){
    date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');
    $result = '<div class="table-responsive">
                <table class="table table-bordered" style="text-align:center; background-color:#fff;">
                <thead>
                    <tr class="table-head">
                        <th>Package</th>
                        <th>Age Category</th>
                        <th>Ticket Price</th>
                        <th>Reg. Link</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>';
    $id = get_the_ID();
    $current_date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
    if( get_field('Race-Categories', $id) ) {
        while( the_repeater_field('Race-Categories', $id) ) {
        $event_start_date .= date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime("+5 hours +30 minutes", strtotime(get_sub_field("ticket_registration_start"))));
        $event_end_date .= date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime("+5 hours +30 minutes", strtotime(get_sub_field("ticket_registration_end_date"))));
        $result .='<tr>';
        $result .='<td>'.get_sub_field("package").'</td>';
        $result .='<td>'.get_sub_field("age_category").'</td>';
        $result .='<td>'.get_sub_field("ticket_price").'</td>';
        if($current_date > $event_start_date){
            $result .= '<td>Registration Open</td>';
        }else{
            $result .= '<td>Registration Close</td>';
        }
        $result .='</tr>';
    }
    }else{
        $result .='No Any Race categories allocated for this event. Try other events.';
    }
    $result .= '</tbody>
                </table>
                </div>';
    return $result;
}
```

But this is returning wrong output, going share below the screenshot of my output..

[image]

It is showing in every row registration open but logically it should be show registration closed and show only registration open for 2 km Family-Run.

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is that you are concatenating the dates in each instance of the loop and should be assigning:

Try changing this:

```
$event_start_date .= date("Y-m-d H:i:s"...
$event_end_date .= date("Y-m-d H:i:s"...
```

To this:

```
$event_start_date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s"...
$event_end_date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s"...
```